# Perpetual Weighted Average cost Calculation SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions, cumulative-sum

I want to calculate Perpetual Weighted Average cost for inventory. I tried to understand a solution on following link
[Inventory Average Cost Calculation in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396827/inventory-average-cost-calculation-in-sql)
but cannot get it, it is complex for me.

here is my database details.

```
Purch_ID  Item_ID   QTY    Unit_Price   

 01         1       10       10               
 02         2       10       20               
 03         3       20       15              
 04         2       10       20               
 05         1       10       18              
 06         2       25       17
```

I want to calculate the Weighted Average cost after each Purchase  using following formula

```
((old_stock x Old unit price)+(New_Purchase_qty x New unit price))/(old stock qty + new purchase qty)
```

any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the cumulative average price.

This approach uses subqueries to calculate the cumulative total quantity and the cumulative total paid.  The ratio is the avg cost:

```
select t.*, cumepaid / cumeqty as avg_cost
from (select t.*,
             (select SUM(qty) from t t2 where t2.item_id = t.item_id and t2.purch_id <= t.purch_id
             ) as cumeqty,
             (select SUM(qty*unit_price) from t t2 where t2.item_id = t.item_id and t2.purch_id <= t.purch_id
             ) as cumepaid
      from t
     ) t
```

In SQL Server 2012, you can do this by directly calculating cumulative sums (should be more efficient).  You could also do this with `cross apply`, but I prefer standard SQL.