# Sql Server version of stock valuation query

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to calculate the average stock price and got following solution
[Inventory Average Cost Calculation in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396827/inventory-average-cost-calculation-in-sql)

this query looks superb as it is exactly what I need

but I am using SQL Server 2008. what will be the Sql Server version for this query??

calculation formula is 
    ((old_stock x Old unit price)+(New_Purchase_qty x New unit price))/(old stock qty + new purchase qty)
record are

```
TrancDate   ProID   Qty CostRate    TrancType  closingStock    closingCostRate
02/06/2013  1   10.000  2.00               P             10                2
02/08/2013  1   7.000   0.00               S             3                 2
02/15/2013  1   15.000  3.00               P             18                2.83
02/16/2013  1   8.000   0.00               S             10                2.83
02/25/2013  1   20.000  4.00               P             30                3.61 
02/26/2013  1   9.000   0.00               S             21                3.61
02/26/2013  1   1.000   0.00               S             20                3.61
```

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: trunc() is effectively the same as casting a float to an int.  decode is a function version of a case construct.  Any other parts on which you are unclear?

Comment: @DanBracuk: The `model` part, perhaps?

Comment: For sample records please check updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the calculation is what I think it is:

```
select t.*, cumetot / cumeqty
from (select t.*,
             (select SUM(qty)
              from t t2
              where t2.tranctype = 'P' and t2.proid = t.proid and t2.trancdate <= t.trancdate
             ) as cumeqty,
             (select SUM(qty*ClosingCostRate)
              from t t2
              where t2.TrancType = 'P' and t2.proid = t.proid and t2.trancdate <= t.trancdate
             ) as cumetot
      from t
     ) t
```

SQL Server 2012 has cumulative sums and counts, but not 2008.

Comment: So I don't need to use partition by ?

Comment: @user1115284 . . . I don't see how that would help.  SQL Server 2008 doesn't have cumulative sums and that is what you need for the running average.  The correlated subquery does the same thing (`t2.proid = t.proid` is equivalent to the `partition` part of a window function).  It might not be as efficient, but it works.

Comment: ok thanks, and what about specifying the TrancType, as average rate should be only calculated when a PURCHASE occurred. other wise all other transactions (SALES) should USE the most recent average rate calculated by Purchase. and of course Stock left after each transaction (both sale and purchase)

Comment: @user1115284 . . . It really is a good idea to have sample data and results in your query.  Perhaps this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740181/perpetual-weighted-average-cost-calculation-sql-server-2008.

Comment: yes the same formula for calculation.Please have a look on edited question

Comment: @user1115284 . . . It was remarkably easy to modify the query.  It only required adding in the `t2.TrancType = 'P'` in the subqueries' `where` clauses.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was still thinking on same partion track and could not spot it. thanks anyway