# how to calculate cost average, postgresql 9.5+

Tags: sql, postgresql

my environtment is postgresql 9.5+

i want to calculate the cost average with window function if possible

eg.

```
kdproduk  code  tgl           qty   harga   totalharga
abc         2   2016-10-20     5    10000   50000
abc         4   2016-10-21    -3    12000   36000   
abc         2   2016-10-22    10    13000   130000
```

then my query is :

```
with ab as (   
  SELECT
      kdproduk,
      code,
      tgl,
      qty,
      harga,
      totalharga,
      coalesce(hargarata2, 0) as hargarata2,
      sum(qty) OVER (PARTITION BY kdproduk ORDER BY kdproduk, tgl, code) AS running_qty
    FROM ms_kartustok
    ORDER BY kdproduk, tgl, code )

select   kdproduk, code, tgl,   qty, harga, totalharga,   coalesce(running_qty, 0) + qty as running_qty,   case
    when code = 2 then (totalharga + coalesce(hargarata2, 0)) / (coalesce(running_qty, 0) + qty)
    else hargarata2   end as rata2 from   (
    SELECT
      kdproduk,
      code,
      tgl,
      qty,
      harga,
      totalharga,
      lag(hargarata2) OVER (PARTITION BY kdproduk ORDER BY kdproduk, tgl, code) AS hargarata2,
      lag(running_qty) OVER (PARTITION BY kdproduk ORDER BY kdproduk, tgl, code) AS running_qty
    FROM ab
    ORDER BY kdproduk, tgl, code   ) as a
```

my query result is :

```
kdproduk  code  tgl           qty   harga   totalharga  running_qty   rata2
abc         2   2016-10-20     5    10000   50000       5             10000
abc         4   2016-10-21    -3    12000   36000       2             0
abc         2   2016-10-22    10    13000   130000      12            10833.333333333334
```

but i want the result is :

```
kdproduk  code  tgl           qty   harga   totalharga  running_qty   rata2
abc         2   2016-10-20     5    10000   50000       5             10000
abc         4   2016-10-21    -3    12000   36000       #2#         #10000#
abc         2   2016-10-22    10    13000   #130000#    12            12500
```

if "code" is 4, then my column "rata2" is the previous "rata2" value. 
if "code" is 2, then my column "rata2" value is :
(totalharga + "rata2 value before") / (qty + "running_qty value before")

the 3rd line is :

```
(130000 + (2*10000)) / (10 + 2) = 12500
```

EDIT: 
see the table above, i use symbol #

how to solved this problem?

thanks.

Comment: You need to explain the logic a bit better.  One part of the question asks for a running average and another has a rather indecipherable description.

Comment: something like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396827/inventory-average-cost-calculation-in-sql

Comment: why in the 3rd case there is `(2*10000)`. Shouldn't it just be `10000`?

Comment: 10000 is rata2, it must be total value of (running_qty * rata2), u can see on the link i make on the comment for clarity